# SAXParser in android and that output store into array

Tags: android, saxparser

I am new android developer and i want create a webservice in php and i want call that webservice and that response in to get in array and that fill into List.

provideing the best user interaction pls help to solve this problems

Thanx in advance

@androidTechs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a class that can be use to make call to webservice called WebService.java

```
package com.blessan;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;

public class WebService {

    private ArrayList <NameValuePair> params;
    private ArrayList <NameValuePair> headers;

    private String url;

    private int responseCode;
    private String message;

    private String response;

    public enum RequestMethod
    {
        GET,POST
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public int getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }

    public WebService(String url)
    {
        this.url = url;
        params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        headers = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    }

    public void AddParam(String name, String value)
    {
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
    }

    public void AddHeader(String name, String value)
    {
        headers.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
    }

    public void Execute(RequestMethod method) throws Exception
    {
        switch(method) {
            case GET:
            {
                //add parameters
                String combinedParams = "";
                if(!params.isEmpty()){
                    combinedParams += "?";
                    for(NameValuePair p : params)
                    {
                        String paramString = p.getName() + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getValue(),"UTF-8");
                        if(combinedParams.length() > 1)
                        {
                            combinedParams  +=  "&" + paramString;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            combinedParams += paramString;
                        }
                    }
                }

                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url + combinedParams);

                //add headers
                for(NameValuePair h : headers)
                {
                    request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
                }

                executeRequest(request, url);
                break;
            }
            case POST:
            {
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

                //add headers
                for(NameValuePair h : headers)
                {   
                    request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
                }

                if(!params.isEmpty()){
                    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
                }

                executeRequest(request, url);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void executeRequest(HttpUriRequest request, String url) throws SocketTimeoutException, ConnectTimeoutException
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpParams params = client.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 10000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 10000);
        HttpResponse httpResponse;

        try {
            httpResponse = client.execute(request);
            responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            message = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {

                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                response = convertStreamToString(instream);

                // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
                instream.close();
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e)  {
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(SocketTimeoutException e){
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new SocketTimeoutException();
        } catch(ConnectTimeoutException e){
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ConnectTimeoutException();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e){
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

This is how you use it from your activity

```
WebService webClient = new WebService(Constants.REQUEST_URL);
        webClient.AddParam("method", "getUserLogin");
        webClient.AddParam("key", Constants.REQUEST_KEY);
        webClient.AddParam("xml_content","<Request>"+
                                             "<Authentication>"+
                                                 "<Username>"+StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(userName.getText().toString().trim())+"</Username>"+
                                                 "<Password>"+StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(passWord.getText().toString().trim())+"</Password>"+
                                                 "<AccountID>"+appContext.getCurrentAccount().accId+"</AccountID>"+
                                             "</Authentication>"+
                                             appContext.getDeviceInfo()+
                                         "</Request>");

        try {           
            webClient.Execute(WebService.RequestMethod.POST);
            String response = webClient.getResponse();
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            GetUserLoginHandler getUserLoginHandler = new GetUserLoginHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(getUserLoginHandler);            
            InputSource input = new InputSource(new StringReader(response));
            xr.parse(input);           

            serverResponse = getUserLoginHandler.getResults();
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        } catch(SocketTimeoutException e){
            errorHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        } catch(ConnectTimeoutException e){
            errorHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if(e.toString().indexOf("ExpatParser$ParseException") != -1){
                errorHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);   
            } else {    
                errorHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        }
```

The GetUserLoginHandler is a handler used to parse the response for this request.

```
package com.blessan;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class GetUserLoginHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    private boolean in_statuscode    = false;
    private boolean in_statusmessage = false;
    private boolean in_userid        = false;
    private boolean in_username      = false;
    private boolean in_accountaccess = false;
    private boolean in_clockstatus   = false;
    private boolean in_timestamp     = false;
    private boolean in_depttransfer  = false;
    private boolean in_currdeptid    = false;
    private boolean in_currdeptname  = false;
    private Map<String, String> results         =   new HashMap<String, String>();

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        if (localName.equals("StatusCode")) {
            this.in_statuscode    = true;
        } else if (localName.equals("StatusMessage")) {
            this.in_statusmessage = true;
        } else if (localName.equals("UserId")) {
            this.in_userid        = true;
        } else if (localName.equals("UserName")) {
            this.in_username      = true;
        } else if (localName.equals("AccountAccess")) {
            this.in_accountaccess = true;
        } else if (localName.equals("ClockStatus")) {
            this.in_clockstatus   = true;
        } else if (localName.equals("Timestamp")) {
            this.in_timestamp     = true;
        } else if (localName.equals("DepartmentTransfer")) {
            this.in_depttransfer  = true;
        } else if (localName.equals("CurrentDepartmentID")) {
            this.in_currdeptid    = true;
        } else if (localName.equals("CurrentDepartmentName")) {
            this.in_currdeptname  = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if (localName.equals("StatusCode")) {
            this.in_statuscode    = false;
        } else if (localName.equals("StatusMessage")) {
            this.in_statusmessage = false;
        } else if (localName.equals("UserId")) {
            this.in_userid        = false;
        } else if (localName.equals("UserName")) {
            this.in_username      = false;
        } else if (localName.equals("AccountAccess")) {
            this.in_accountaccess = false;
        } else if (localName.equals("ClockStatus")) {
            this.in_clockstatus   = false;
        } else if (localName.equals("Timestamp")) {
            this.in_timestamp     = false;
        } else if (localName.equals("DepartmentTransfer")) {
            this.in_depttransfer  = false;
        } else if (localName.equals("CurrentDepartmentID")) {
            this.in_currdeptid    = false;
        } else if (localName.equals("CurrentDepartmentName")) {
            this.in_currdeptname  = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
        if (this.in_statuscode) {
            results.put("StatusCode", new String(ch, start, length));
        } if (this.in_statusmessage) {
            results.put("StatusMessage", new String(ch, start, length));
        } if (this.in_userid) {
            results.put("UserId", new String(ch, start, length));
        } if (this.in_username) {
            results.put("UserName", new String(ch, start, length));
        } if (this.in_accountaccess) {
            results.put("AccountAccess", new String(ch, start, length));
        } if (this.in_clockstatus) {
            results.put("ClockStatus", new String(ch, start, length));
        } if (this.in_timestamp) {
            results.put("Timestamp", new String(ch, start, length));
        } if (this.in_depttransfer) {
            results.put("DepartmentTransfer", new String(ch, start, length));
        } if (this.in_currdeptid) {
            results.put("CurrentDepartmentID", new String(ch, start, length));
        } if (this.in_currdeptname) {
            results.put("CurrentDepartmentName", new String(ch, start, length));
        }
    }

    public Map<String, String> getResults(){
        return results;
    }
}
```

This is just an example. There are many tutorials explaining SAX parsing in detail.